# NameError: variable @dl-horizontal-offset is undefined

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, less

I've installed bootstrap from source and couldn't compile any less files. Then I switched to bower and got similar errors like this:

```
NameError: variable @dl-horizontal-offset is undefined in /bower_components/bootstrap/less/type.less on line 222, column 15:
221 float: left;
222 width: (@dl-horizontal-offset - 20);
223 clear: left;
```

Here's what bower installed and updated:

```
$ bower update
bower cached git://github.com/twbs/bootstrap.git#3.2.0
bower validate 3.2.0 against git://github.com/twbs/bootstrap.git#~3.2.0
bower cached git://github.com/jquery/jquery.git#2.1.1
bower validate 2.1.1 against git://github.com/jquery/jquery.git#>= 1.9.0
```

I've also found out that adding the variables defined in gists such as https://gist.github.com/amondilado/66a31dd7813b6df400bd make the compile errors go away. However, why I am getting the errors in the first place? How do I solve the problem without using the gist?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24769277/why-cant-koala-compile-the-default-bootstrap-3-less-files#comment38439753_24769277

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this same problem using Gulp and Bootstrap 3. My issue was with the first line of bootstrap.less.

```
// Core variables and mixins
@import "variables.less"; // Modify this for custom colors, font-sizes, etc
```

I had the wrong variables.less file from an older version of Bootstrap or something. The file I wanted was in "../Bootstrap/less/variables.less". Since I didn't have any customizations yet, copying the file seems fine to me.

As a test, if you go into the variables file that you have now in bootstrap.less and the undefined variable isn't there but is in the variables file one level down, then you probably need to change where that is pointing. I may be adding a step to upgrading Bootstrap in the future with copying over the variables file, but this worked for me.

Comment: Thanks! I've discovered a similar thing i.e. the @import wasn't picking up the files installed with bower. All I did was supply the correct path (just like you did) and got it working.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into similar issue for @dl-horizontal-breakpoint. Above solution did not work for me. So I replaced this variable in type.less with it's corresponding value (value after colon ':') from variable.less i.e "@grid-float-breakpoint" worked for me.

[Screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P4RrO.png)